# SFDX: command to retrieve Compact Layout from Source org to Visual Studio Code

Tags: lightning-experience, salesforcedx-cli, sfdx-plugin, visualstudiocode, compact-layout

I want to retrieve Compact layout to visual studio code from the source org. Currently I'm using following command.

**sfdx force:source:retrieve -m "CompactLayout:Lead-English Courses"**

But using this command , terminal returns "No Result found".

Can anyone help me to solve this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems you are using the compact layout label u need to **use the API Name**
and then
sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CompactLayout:Account.Mobile_Account_Layout

Note: the format for source: retrieve is **objectAPI.compactLayoutAPI**

Answer (score 2):

Below are some useful sfdx commands for retrieval

- **Custom field**

sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomField:ObjectApiName.FieldNameApi

***eg:sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CustomField:Account.B2C_Fiscal_Year__c***

- **Page Layout**

sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Layout-"ObjectApiName.Page Layout Name"

***eg:sfdx force:source:retrieve -m Layout-"Account.B2C Summer21 Courses"***

- **Compact Layout**

sfdx force:source:retrieveCompactLayout:ObjectApiName.CompactLayoutApiName

***eg:sfdx force:source:retrieve -m CompactLayout:Account.B2C_Summer21_Courses_compact_layout***

- **Record Types**

sfdx force:source:retrieve -m RecordType:ObjectApiName:RecordTypeName

***eg:sfdx force:source:retrieve -m RecordType:Account.B2C_Summer21_Courses***